# ICollection <T> to string array (using string property)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, icollection

I have an `ICollection` of `Thing`. `Thing` has a `string` property `Name`. I would like to get an array of all `Name` in my `ICollection`. I know I can do this by iterating over the collection and building the array, but is there a neater way to do this with lambda notation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, LINQ lets you do this very easily:

```
string[] names = things.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Of course if you're just going to iterate over it, you don't need the `ToArray` part:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = things.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Or you could create a `List<string>` with `ToList`:

```
List<string> names = things.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

In all of these cases you could use `var` instead of explicitly declaring the variable type - I've only included the type here for clarity.

Using `ToList` can be very slightly more efficient than using `ToArray`, as the final step in `ToArray` involves copying from a possibly-oversized buffer to a right-sized array.

EDIT: Now we know you really *do* need an array, it would be *slightly* more efficient to do this yourself with a manual loop, as you know the size beforehand. I'd definitely use the first form until I knew it was a problem though :)

Comment: Thanks - the reason I want an array of string is to implement the method `GetRolesForUser` for my `RoleProvider` ... I'm not anticipating any big arrays being returned

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: Right - if you definitely want a string array, then the first one is what you're after.